# Ввод диапазона в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Хочу иметь возможность ввода диапазона значений в python. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким регулярным выражением можно описать ввод диапазона вида:
число1 - число2

Comment: Вы хотите выделить начало и конец диапазона из строки `число1 - число2` или хотите получить регулярное выражение, которым можно проверить попадает-ли любое проверяемое число в указанный диапазон?

Comment: @ReinRaus, не дубликат, потому что в том вопросе спрашивается про числа одинаковой длины, что является частным случаем этого вопроса.

Comment: @tutankhamun Я хочу выделить начало и конец из диапазона.

Comment: @Qwertiy не помню точно, как писал генерацию регулярного выражения, завтра утром я обновлю ответ в том вопросе- хочу перевести весь код в сниппет, чтобы можно было генерировать при помощи самого ответа. Делать буду общий случай, так что, если есть недочет - завтра он будет устранен.

Answer (score 0):

Например регулярное выражение для проверки значений от 0 до 100 будет выглядеть так: 
`^0*([0-9]{1,2}|100)$`